# How to read string in bash or convert integer to string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

The following code :

```
read var
gsettings org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "'$var'"
```

for the input sat, 10, reads var as integer. and gives the error

> can not parse as value of type 'i':
>   '10'

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: This doesn't really have as much to do with bash as `gsettings` and how it interprets literal arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the single quotes from the command line; the command expects the string it sees to be a number, and numbers don't start with a single quote.

```
read var
gsettings org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "$var"
```